# How to set a axis with half length

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

This is a illustration of my idea. To plot three attributes in one figure.

I want to set my axes system like the style below. The top axes is range from 0 - 1; The bottom axes is range from -1~1.

Is there any way to achieve that?

```
+------+             ---+ 
|      |         
|      |   --->  
|      |         
+------+         +-------
```

Comment: I think the ascii image is too simplistic to convey the necessary information. Could you either add more information or a better image of what you are trying to achieve? Also, in order to help, it might be good to know where exactly you have problems achieving this.

Answer (score 1):

One can position two axes on top of each other, one being half as wide as the other. Then setting the axes spines invisible and adjusting the axes limits, a plot similar to the one in the question is produced.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,3))
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1, 0.35,0.8])
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.55,0.1, 0.35,0.8])
ax3 = fig.add_axes([0.55+0.175,0.1, 0.175,0.8], facecolor=(0,0,0,0))
ax3.xaxis.tick_top()
ax2.set_xlim([-1,1])
ax3.set_xlim([0,1])

ax2.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax3.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax2.spines['left'].set_color('none')
ax3.spines['left'].set_color('none')
ax2.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax3.spines['bottom'].set_color('none')
ax2.set_yticks([])
ax3.set_yticks([])


x = np.linspace(-1,1,201)
f = lambda x,b: np.sin(x/b)
f2 = lambda x,a,b: ((x/b-a)*np.exp(-(x/b-a)**2))**2

ax1.plot(x, f(x,0.5)*f2(x,1,0.5),  color="C3")
ax2.plot(x,f2(x, -1.8,0.5),  color="C1")
ax3.plot(x,f(x,0.1), color="C2")

ax3.set_ylim([-3,1.5])

plt.show()
```